# What is the maximum number of slots the Eleth Mixer can have?

Tags: tales-of-graces-f

As you use the Eleth Mixer it gains experience and increases the number of items you can assign to it at one time. What is the maximum amount of Eleth it can possibly hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum number of slots it can have is 16. You can only increase the number of slots by creating new items.